# Solving $\frac{(1+x)(1+2x)(1+3x)}{(4+x)(4+2x)(4+3x)}=4 $. Simply bringing it to a common denominator does not lead me to success

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I solve this equation?

$$\frac{(1+x)(1+2x)(1+3x)}{(4+x)(4+2x)(4+3x)}=4 $$

Simply bringing it to a common denominator does not lead me to success

What I tried

[image]

Comment: Do not expand the denominator. The numerator has a rational root. When you get it, use long division and get a quadratic (easy to solve).

Comment: Now you need to find the roots of numerator, and verify they do not match with roots of the denominator.

Comment: how do I find a number that will be zero for my numerator? otherwise, I can't share. I think it's fractional.

Comment: Every coefficient in the numerator is a multiple of three.

Comment: Wolfram-alpha can do this.

Answer (score 2):

We have that for $(4+x)(4+2x)(4+3x)\neq0 $

$$\frac{(1+x)(1+2x)(1+3x)}{(4+x)(4+2x)(4+3x)}=4  \iff 18 x^3 + 165 x^2 + 378 x + 255=0$$

$$\iff 6 x^3 + 35 x^2 + 126 x + 85=0$$

and by [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) we can find that $x=-\frac 5 3$ is a root and then we obtain

$$6 x^3 + 35 x^2 + 126 x + 85=(3 x + 5) (2 x^2 + 15 x + 17)$$

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on not dealing with a cubic equation, then maybe this can work. Notice:
$$\dfrac{(1+x)(1+2x)(1+3x)}{(4+x)(4+2x)(4+3x)} = \dfrac{(1+x)(-1-2x)(1+3x)}{(4+x)(-4-2x)(4+3x)} = \dfrac{a(b-c)(c-4)}{b(a-c)(c-1)} = 4$$
where $c = 3x+5$, $a = x+1$ and $b = x+4.$ If you expand this quadratic in $c:$
$$c^2(a-4b)+c(3ab+4b-4a) = 0$$
and this one is easy to solve.

But I must say that learning how to factor cubic if they have nice solutions by the Rational Root Theorem etc is much more useful than trying to find clever substitutions. The other answer already covers that.

Comment: @lonestudent not really. In fact, even substituting $c = 3x+1000$ works because of the presence of $x,2x,3x$ since $x+2x = 3x$ and thus it eliminates one order. If you think no one can observe things like this beforehand, then you obviously haven't done enough math competitions in your high school.

Comment: I don't think you have a clue as to what I am saying. The three linear terms being present means you can reduce the degree by one with literally any substitution because they are affinely dependent. As to why $3x+5$, it is literally staring in your face:
$$(1+x)+(4+2x) = 3x+5 = (1+2x)+(4+x).$$
I cannot explain it any simpler.

Comment: I deleted my comments because I didn't get what I wanted from you.

Answer (score -1):

\begin{equation}
\frac{(1+x)(1+2x)(1+3x)}{(4+x)(4+2x)(4+3x)}
=4 \\
\text{We multiply both sides by teh common denominator}\\ 
(1+x)(1+2x)(1+3x\quad =\quad 4\big((4+x)(4+2x)(4+3x)\big)  \\
\text{we expand both sides} \\
 x^3 + 11 x^2 + 6 x + 1\quad =\quad 24 x^3 + 176 x^2 + 384 x + 256\\
\text{we collect terms} \\ 
18 x^3 + 165 x^2 + 378 x + 255=0\\ 
\text{we factor} \\  
3 (3 x + 5) (2 x^2 + 15 x + 17)=0\\ \\
\text{we solve} \\  
x = -5/3
\qquad\quad\space\space \space  \approx -1.6667\\ 
x = \frac{-15 + \sqrt{89}}{4}
\quad\approx  -1.3915\\
x = \frac{-15 - \sqrt{89}}{4}
\quad\approx -6.1085
\end{equation}